# What is this vintage small airplane with low wings and twin propeller engines?

Tags: aircraft-identification

Could anyone help me to identify this vintage aircraft, that can be seen in the background of this photograph, please?
[image: vintage aircraft]

Comment: The photo is probably from the 60s, as the car is a 'ZAZ 965', a Soviet copy of the 'Fiat 600'...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It's a LET L-200 Morava, a Czech plane...
http://www.aviastar.org/air/czech/let_l-200.php

Comment: The props in the original picture appear to have two blades, while the props on the picture on that site you linked has three. Is that simply a different configuration?

Comment: It's morava refinement: _The original production model was superseded first by the generally similar L-200A, with more powerful Walter M 337 engines and, subsequently, by the final production version, the L-200D, which was introduced in mid-1962. This differed by in-corporating improved systems, strengthened landing gear, and three-bladed constant-speed propellers._